# Create a Java Bean to be of type HashSet and get error in editor

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans

This is my code:

```
package ca.wfsystems.core;

import lotus.domino.Base;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;



import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;
import ca.wfsystems.core.*;


**public class ssAppMenu implements Serializable , HashSet<String>{**

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ssAppMenu(){

    }

}
```

The public class line gives this error:
The type HashSet cannot be a superinterface of ssAppMenu; a superinterface must be an interface

All I want is a set of values in a list in the order I place them. I don't need a  construct. From what I have read I believe the HashSet does that but not sure how to format the public class line.

Comment: `implements` is used with interfaces HashSet is an actual class not an interface, hence the error you got. Could you give more details on your actual problem statement in the question? "to be of type HashSet" isn't completely clear. And why not just Set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashSet is an implementation of interface Set. You need to define

```
public class ssAppMenu extends LinkedHashSet<String> implements Serializable
```

Comment: I think what I really want is a LinkedHashSet because I want to ensure the order of the elements are as I load them, and if I read the definitions correctly then the LinkedHashSet does that. I don't want it sorted but I do want the Order maintained.

Comment: @BillF: If order is important, consider implementing interface `SortedSet`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Comment: @LauriLaanti: I do not want the set to be sorted I need it to be in the sequence as I load it, which may or may not be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

HashSet is a class, not an interface. Don't implement, extend it.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html